# Get rows from Sqlite android DB comparing date after today

Tags: android, database, sqlite, date

I'm quite new to android developement and i would like to know how to get rows from Sqlite android DB comparing dates after today.

My dates are stored in database in this format:

```
"Tue Jun 17 17:30:00 CEST 2014"
```

I get the current date like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dfm = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
String now = dfm.format(cal.getTime());
```

My query is:(bdd is my SQLiteDatabase)

```
Cursor c = bdd.rawQuery( "select * from sportevent WHERE DATE > " + now , null);
```

I have also tried to do:

```
Cursor c = bdd.rawQuery( "select * from sportevent WHERE DATE > date('now') , null);
```

Among other things i'have also tried to use :

```
strftime('EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy',"+ "'" +now +"')" to compare dates
```

without any success...

Do i have to store my dates as Long to compare dates?

I must have missed something...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: SQLite does not have date DATATYPE for storing values

Comment: You must use one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).

Comment: Thanks for your answers. From what i have understood, my date is stored as a String in this format "Tue Jun 17 17:30:00 CEST 2014" or as the documentation says as TEXT as ISO8601 strings. @CL, You mean that this format "Tue Jun 17 17:30:00 CEST 2014" is not supported?

Comment: Your format is not supported because it is not [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: @CL you are right. I have changed the way i saved my dates and used this pattern to save and retrieve/parse my dates : SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",Locale.FRENCH); This format seems to be ISO 8601 and comparing dates with < or > works now in my query. You are the best, Thank you so much!